# Getting a thumbnail image from google books api into a python variable

Tags: python, json, image, api, thumbnails

I can do this OK both in js and php but not in python.  I'm trying to pull a thumbnail image from google books api into a python variable.
The text objects are fine eg

```
newTitle = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['title'])
isbn10 = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][1]['identifier'])
isbn13 = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier'])
```

The image is supplied in the api as follows. (if you put the http// url into a browser you see the image):

```
"imageLinks": {
          "smallThumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=XUnNDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api",
          "thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=XUnNDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
```

I have tried the simple:

```
myImage = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail])
```

which doesn't work.
I have installed pillow to provide image management:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail]") or 
img = Image.open(parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail])
```

which doesn't work. I have tried more complex arrangements:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail])
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

but nothing seems to work.  I have tried many other variations on these attempts.  I have also, unsuccessfully tried to load the text that points to the thumbnail to try another route.  I am confident that the "['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail]" is correct though my only way of testing whether the variable is properly loaded is to save it or if the line of code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have problems downloading and opening the image.
I have use the following code

```
import requests
from PIL import Image


image_url = "https://books.google.com/books/content?id=XUnNDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api"
  
r = requests.get(image_url)
  
with open("demo_image",'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

img = Image.open("demo_image")
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  That works for me OK too, but if I replace the direct link with the json link eg "image_url = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks'][thumbnail])" the code stops there.  I'll try different variations for the json syntax in case that is the problem. If anyone knows how to get that url out of the parsed json - I'd be overwhelmingly grateful!

Comment: Its working now with:   "image_url = (parsed_json['items'][0]['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['thumbnail'])" .  I forgot the commas on 'thumbnail' .  Sorry for wasting time.  Thanks for the reply though.  Hopefully someone might find the request and answer useful though